# Reality Check for friend

Tags: united-states, inheritance

A friend from China just inherited from grandparents in Shanghai (from a very wealthy family) these items. Who could I contact to discover their authenticity and help her perhaps understand the best direction for her if they are real.

She has what says it is a 1935 $10,000,000 Treasury Bond, with an original receipt, original envelope, all with official stamps paid for with 325000 G of the T50 rectangular gold and 1500 G of gold hair pins valued at $10,000,000.  I have pictures of all this but can not get them to post here

Comment: This is a definite scam. If your "friend" tries to get you involved in *any* way, run. They are not your friend if they are trying to scam you.

Comment: https://www.treasurydirect.gov/email.htm

Comment: https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/ig/Pages/Scams/Examples-of-Known-Phony-Securities.aspx

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea those "U.S. Dollar Bonds" are a riot.  Even ignoring the skeevy parts which the Treasury Dept noted...  Ministry of Finance of the USA?  Washington Bank of America?  LOL

Comment: The US Treasury does not accept gold hair pins as payment.

Answer (score 9):

The figures – as quoted – don't appear to stack up.

A search for "*gold price 1935*" yields a figure of $35 per **troy ounce** (see [here](http://onlygold.com/Info/Historical-Gold-Prices.asp) and [here](http://nma.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Historical-Gold-Prices.pdf)) with the same for the years either side.

Assuming the "**G**" in the question is **grammes**, then 326,500g is equivalent to 10,497oz which would only have a value **$367,395**, not $10M.

Even if the "G" *was* (troy) ounces, then 326,500oz would have been worth **$11,427,500** which is nearer the mark. However, [this US Treasury page](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/other/res_othersecurities.htm) shows 1935 Treasury Bonds to have been issued at 75% face value, so $11.5M of gold should have bought bonds with a face-value of slightly over $15M.

Finally, that site lists the denominations as $25, $50, $100, $500 and $1,000, so  "***a** 1935 $10,000,000 Treasury Bond*" doesn't sound correct (unless there were other denominations not mentioned).

Comment: Agreed. This looks more like a scam.

Comment: Gold prices are usually quoted in dollars per ounce but the ounce is often the [troy ounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_weight) which is 31.10 grammes whereas the common avoirdupois ounce is 28.35 grammes. Thus, 326,500 grammes would be 10,498 (troy) ounces.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for pointing that out. I _knew_ gold is measured in troy ounces, but forgot to specify that when making the conversion from grammes. Have updated answer.

Comment: That link is for (mostly) _Savings_ Bonds which traditionally were mostly sold at discount and in small amounts, although as shown E F G H J K existed in larger denominations. [Regular marketable bonds are here](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/tbonds/res_tbond.htm) and nowadays are only book-entry and don't need denominations; historically paper bonds did have varying denominations -- [wikipedia links to a site](https://www.theherbstmancollection.com/bonds-1933--) with specimens up to 5k and 10k -- and I don't know how high they went, but 10m seems implausible.

Comment: That said, it still sounds like a scam.

Answer (score 2):

I did some casual digging. I do not think that my numbers are quite scientifically sound but they do put the scale of a ten million dollar bond in frame for 1935. I think it may make sense to merge my answer with @TripeHound as he/she worked a similar vein by working out gold prices.

GDP in 1935 was $0.074 trillion dollars (thats $74 billion) per https://www.thebalance.com/us-gdp-by-year-3305543

If my math is right that would make a $10M bond be 0.00013% of US GDP for the year. That doesn't seem like a huge number but its a massive amount for a single bond. If a bond of a a similar scale were issued today for 0.00013% of GDP, it would be $2.4 billion. No one would escape scrutiny for trying to buy $2.4 billion dollars in a single bond.

In 1935 there were 41 people in the US who earned over $1M/year per the IRS https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/35soireppt1ar.pdf . A bond that pays out at ten times the highest recorded income bracket in the US would simply not have been affordable to anyone at the time except maybe a foreign government.

Working backwards from @TripeHounds numbers that $10M bond would have cost $7.5M. In 1935 very very few people had that kind of money or gold available to buy a bond with.